# Wicket 6.19 order of import changes after replacing wicket's ajax js file

Tags: javascript, java, wicket, wicket-6

i am using `wicket 6.19`
There was a need to replace wicket's existing `wicket-ajax-jquery.js` in the application because of a bug in it which causes t he timers to freeze after you download a file.
So, the fix was to use `unload` event instead of `beforeunload` event in the said js this fix is available in 6.20 onwards.
Since i cannot upgrade to higher versions due to some constraints i was trying this manual patch to make it work.
But now when i see the HTML after page gets loaded the order of js import changes.
First the `wicket-ajax-jquery.js` is loaded and then the `jquery.js` followed by `wicket-event-jquery.js`
Need help here to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you patch Wicket's JavaScript file?

A simple solution is to replace it in your application:

```
addResourceReplacement(WicketAjaxJQueryResourceReference.get(), new PackageResourceReference(getClass(), "wicket-ajax-jquery-patched.js"));
```

Comment: i still see the patched ajax js first in the import hierarchy followed by jquery and event js because which i get javascript reference errors.

Comment: Your PackageResourceReference should depend on WicketEventJQueryResourceReference. See "Dependency management" in http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-resource-management/